# Error passing information within promises

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have three functions: [getLocation, getWeather, displayWeather]

I would like displayWeather to use async, and call the other functions, but i'm getting an error from getWeather(), stating something went wrong from reject().

I understand there's an issue somewhere getting lat, lon positions, but can't figure out where my issues are coming from.

Definitely new to JS Promises, and would love some support.

Thanks very much

```
import Card from "../Card/Card";
import { useState } from "react";

const WeatherCard = () => {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState([]); // array default

  const getLocation = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // if location is enabled in browser
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        // get [lat, lon] coordinates, passes to setLocation()
        resolve(
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
            // set location state to array [lat, lon]
            setLocation([position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude]);
          })
        );
        // if location isn't enabled in browser
      } else {
        // error message
        reject(console.log("Please enable location services"));
      }
    });
  };

  // takes in location [lat, lon] and returns weather data
  const getWeather = (lat, lon) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // if location state has values
      if (location.length > 0) {
        resolve(
          // get data from api (api key is in .env file)
          fetch(
            `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&exclude={part}&appid=${process.env.REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY}`
          )
            // parse data to json
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
              // write weather data to console
              console.log(data);
            })
        );
        // if location state has no values
      } else {
        // error message
        reject(console.log("Something went wrong getting the api"));
      }
    });
  };

  // displays weather data to user (async function)
  const displayWeather = async () => {
    // get location
    await getLocation();
    //pass in location state [lat, lon] to getWeather()
    await getWeather(location[0], location[1]).catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

  // rendered elements
  return (
    <Card>
      <div>{location}</div>
      <button onClick={displayWeather}>Click</button>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default WeatherCard;
```

Comment: Check out [this article on Promise anti-patterns](https://runnable.com/blog/common-promise-anti-patterns-and-how-to-avoid-them), in particular the section on "Creating New Promises." I'm not saying necessarily that this is the root of your problem, but it jumped out at me on first glance.

Comment: Can you post the error you're getting? Also, it would help a lot if you posted a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).